# Reproducing a font style

Tags: fonts

How to reproduce this font style please?

[image]

I've tried this, but it wouldn't work.

> \large\normalfont{Najeh}

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `\large\textsf{Najeh}`.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
{\large\sffamily Najeh}
\end{document}`  Likewise `\usepackage{palatino}` could be used in place of `times`, since they appear to use the same sans serif font family.

Comment: @Jubobs perhaps `{\large\sffamily Najeh}` would be better (to keep also `\large` local).

Comment: Don't use `times`...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

This code uses a replacement for `times` which better supports maths and scales the sans-serif font appropriately:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
\RequirePackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\RequirePackage{courier}

\begin{document}

\large\textsf{Najeh}

\end{document}
```

[image: <code>helvet</code> scaled]

Alternatively, you could use fonts from TeX Gyre:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{tgtermes}
\RequirePackage{tgheros}
\RequirePackage{tgcursor}

\begin{document}

\large\textsf{Najeh}

\end{document}
```

[image: <code>tgheros</code>]